# Constructing a Mobius transformation that acts on any two points of the upper half complex plane:

Tags: complex-analysis, projective-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I would like to construct a Mobius transformation that sends any two points $z_1$ and  $z_2$ from the upper half of the complex plane to i and to $iR^+$, i.e., given any two points $z_1$ and $z_2$, and a Mobius transform A, then A($z_1$) = i, while A($z_2$) goes to *some* place on the vertical line $iR^+$.

This transform A belongs in the group of matrices PSL(2,R), the projective special linear group of 2x2 real matrices, with determinant = 1.

Any thoughts on how I can construct this mapping (and have it be a member of PSL(2,R))?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. Map to the unit disk so that $z_1$ goes to center.
2. Rotate the disk so that the image of $z_2$ is real.
3. Map back to the upper half plane with $z\mapsto i\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}$.
4. The composition of the above maps achieves the goal.
5. Any Möbius transformation of the upper halfplane onto itself is represented by a $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ matrix; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Subgroups_of_the_M.C3.B6bius_group).